Sendmail bounces bounce back
I get mail sent to a former user. Their account is gone, so the mail gets bounced, but the bounce itself is bounced back to me. It seems clear enough that this is a spam server, and accepts no mail. What's a good way to detect this and do something more clever, such as blacklist the sender or fail2ban the server?

Do you mean a script? Oh wait… too late!

So I’ve just written you a simple draft script, but:
I’ve just assumed you're using a Linux-based mail server with access to the mail command and a blacklist file.
-Obviously you'll need to edit it to fit your specific setup.
-This is only a rough draft and they may be some errors, as well as, like I said, some things you’ll need to change. Just don’t go copy/pasting this in- it probably won’t work.
bash
#!/bin/bash

# Set the blacklist file location
BLACKLIST_FILE=/path/to/blacklist

# Process bounced emails
for email in /var/mail/bounced/*.eml; do
  # Extract the sender's address from the bounce message
  SENDER=$(grep -oP 'from=<\K[^>]+>' "$email")

  # Check if the sender is already blacklisted
  if grep -Fxq "$SENDER" "$BLACKLIST_FILE"; then
    # If blacklisted, discard the email and continue
    echo "Blacklisted sender: $SENDER"
    continue
  fi

  # Analyze the bounce message (e.g., check for spam patterns)
  # ...

  # If the sender appears to be a spam server, add them to the blacklist
  if [ /* your analysis condition */ ]; then
    echo "$SENDER" >> "$BLACKLIST_FILE"
    echo "Added $SENDER to blacklist"
  fi
done

So yeah… that was kinda long, and sorry if you’re new to coding and it’s a bit confusing- but again- it’s only a rough draft.
Now this is how to actually ude it:

Save this script as a file (e.g., bounce_handler.sh).
Make the script executable with chmod +x bounce_handler.sh.
Configure your mail server to pipe bounced emails to this script (e.g., using a .forward file or the mail server configuration setting).
Set up a cron job to run the script regularly (like every 15 minutes).

Let me know how it goes!

I was hoping for an intervention which happens when sendmail finds it can't contact the sending SMPTD. I can't be the only person this happens to...

Ohhh… so this doesn’t work or it’s not quite what you’re looking for? I think I know what you mean…

Right, so let's say some remote smtp server we'll call R hands my sendmail a message for ex-user "A". My server accepts it, and tries to deliver it locally. The local mailer says "no such user". My sendmail then tries to send a bounce mail back to R, but R doesn't have a listener open. This is not a good sign, but it's not unreasonable, yet. It might be down for maintenance. So my server tries for five days to send the bounce.
However, I have special knowledge: I know that user A has been gone for a while, so any server trying to send to him here is a spammer or at least poorly set up.

I then get a mailbox full of bounces to a server not following SMTP etiquette. I get all the trash, Remote server is unbothered by it.
